# Binding to parameters with odbc_exec

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

I am using a Microsoft Access Database and am connected to it by ODBC in my PHP code. I have looked online and the PHP manual says that `odbc_exec` prepares and executes the statement.

My code has parameters to avoid an sql injection but I cannot use `odbc_prepare` and `odbc_execute` as they are not supported by MS Access. I am having trouble finding out how to bind my variables to the parameters in my sql statement.

**PHP**

```
<?php

$con=odbc_connect("InventoryDB", "", ""); 

if (isset($_POST['partNumber'])) {
    $partNum = $_POST['partNumber'];
}

if (isset($_POST['manufacturer'])) {
    $manufacturer = $_POST['manufacturer'];
}

if (isset($_POST['supplier'])) {
    $supplier = $_POST['supplier'];
}

if (isset($_POST['catalogNumber'])) {
    $catalogNumber = $_POST['catalogNumber'];
}

if (isset($_POST['deviceFamily'])) {
    $deviceFamily = $_POST['deviceFamily'];
}

if (isset($_POST['listPrice'])) {
    $listPrice = $_POST['listPrice'];
}

if (isset($_POST['quantity'])) {
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
}

if (isset($_POST['packets'])) {
    $packets = $_POST['packets'];
}



$stmt = odbc_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO Parts (PartNumber, Manufacturer, Supplier, CatalogNumber, DeviceFamily, ListPrice, Quantity, Packets) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'); // Insert all of the values from the form into the table
$rs = odbc_execute($stmt, array($partNum, $manufacturer, $supplier, $catalogNumber, $deviceFamily, $listPrice, $quantity, $packets));

?>
```

I would like to know how to do what I am currently doing with prepare and execute using just `odbc_exec`.

The values all come from a form to add to the database which shows the inventory of a company.

**EDIT**

The error that using prepare and execute returns is `odbc_prepare()`:

> SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this
>   function, SQL state IM001 in SQLDescribeParameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider PHP's generalized DB-API, [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php), that among other RBDMS's can connect to MS Access via ODBC for [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). You may need to enable `php_pdo_odbc` in .ini file:

```
$database = "C:\\path\\to\\mydatabase.accdb";

// WITH DSN
$dbh = new PDO("odbc:DSN=MS Access Database;DBq=$database;");
// WITH DRIVER
// $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBq=$database;");

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "INSERT INTO Parts (PartNumber, Manufacturer, Supplier, CatalogNumber, 
                           DeviceFamily, ListPrice, Quantity, Packets) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";  

try {
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
    $sth->execute(array($partNum, $manufacturer, $supplier, $catalogNumber, 
                        $deviceFamily, $listPrice, $quantity, $packets));
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
}

// CLOSE CONNECTION
$dbh = null;
```

Comment: The OP asked how to do this explicitly with odbc_exec, and this answer says "use PDO"... I wouldn't call that an answer imo.

Comment: @SourceMatters, at the time of writing this solution, `odbc_prepare` does not support parameters for MS Access which OP is attempting. PDO does support params.

Answer (score -2):

If you can't use `odbc_prepare` you have to generate your SQL statement as a string and do the best you can to defend against SQL injection. By far the biggest problem is the `'` character. I use these two functions:

```
function Qs($Text) { return(str_replace("'","''",$Text)); }
function Qsz($Text) { return(empty($Text)?'NULL':("'".Qs($Text)."'")); }
```

The first just avoids issues with `'`. I use the second if I want to insert `NULL` instead of an empty string (usually the case).

Use double quotes on generating your SQL statement, so they don't conflict with the single quotes inside the statement. Example (assuming both fields are text):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Parts (PartNumber, Manufacturer) VALUES (".Qsz($_POST['partNumber']).",".Qsz($_POST['partNumber']).")";
```

Comment: Why can't you use `odbc_prepare`? And your answer is open to SQL injection!

Comment: @Parfait odbc_prepare isnt supported by MS Access